# Apache Commons FTP Library - retrieveFile function download failed

Tags: java

Could you please give me a hint what am I doing wrong? This code crashes (exception e) after calling retrieveFile. I'm trying to download a file from IIS FTP (to which I can successfuly connect) into SD card (.iso file attached to the emulator). File 'test.txt' exists in main directory of FTP and printWorkingDirectory() shows "/". I did write permissions into manifest and tried without .txt extensions.

```
try {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test2.txt");
    Log.e(TAG, "1 " + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
    file.mkdir();
    FileOutputStream desFileStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    Log.e(TAG, "2 " + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
    status = mFTPClient.retrieveFile("/"+"test.txt", desFileStream);
    Log.e(TAG, "3");
    desFileStream.close();

    return status;
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "download failed");
}
```

10-20 18:02:03.498: E/(1380): 1 /storage/sdcard 
10-20 18:02:03.507: E/(1380): 2 /storage/sdcard
10-20 18:02:03.777: W/System.err(1380): java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 63564): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

10-20 18:02:03.816: W/System.err(1380):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)

10-20 18:02:03.816: W/System.err(1380):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)

10-20 18:02:03.847: W/System.err(1380):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)

10-20 18:02:03.847: W/System.err(1380):     at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:566)

10-20 18:02:03.867: W/System.err(1380):     at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:127)

10-20 18:02:03.887: W/System.err(1380):     at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:177)

10-20 18:02:03.917: W/System.err(1380):     at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:149)

10-20 18:02:03.967: W/System.err(1380):     at javax.net.DefaultSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultSocketFactory.java:40)

10-20 18:02:03.988: W/System.err(1380):     at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.*openDataConnection*(FTPClient.java:502)

10-20 18:02:04.029: W/System.err(1380):     at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.retrieveFile(FTPClient.java:1276)

10-20 18:02:04.083: W/System.err(1380):     at com.prgguru.android.FTP.ftpDownload(FTP.java:170)

10-20 18:02:04.156: W/System.err(1380):     at com.prgguru.android.Caller5.run(Caller5.java:28)

10-20 18:02:04.156: W/System.err(1380): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

10-20 18:02:04.177: W/System.err(1380):     at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)

10-20 18:02:04.177: W/System.err(1380):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)

10-20 18:02:04.197: W/System.err(1380):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)

10-20 18:02:04.197: W/System.err(1380):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)

10-20 18:02:04.217: W/System.err(1380):     ... 11 more

10-20 18:02:04.217: E/(1380): DOWNLOAD failed

Here how I connect to the FTP before calling retrieveFile:

```
    public static boolean ftpConnect(String host, String username,
        String password, int port) {
    try {
        mFTPClient = new FTPClient();

        mFTPClient.connect(host, port);
        if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(mFTPClient.getReplyCode())) {
            boolean status = mFTPClient.login(username, password);
            mFTPClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            mFTPClient.setFileTransferMode(org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

            return status;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error: could not connect to host " + host);
    }

    return false;
}
```

status returns TRUE for data:

```
private static String host = "10.0.2.2";
private static String user = "MyCorrectNickname";
private static String password = "CorrectPassword";
```

Tried wrong password - returns false.

Comment: You're swallowing up the exception and not outputting the stacktrace. Start there and see what type of exception and error message you're actually receiving.

Comment: Please include the stack trace of Exception e. You can do this by invoking printStackTrace() from the exception object.

Comment: Ok - log added, it says sth about "failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 63564): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)" BUT before invoking retrieveFile I successfully connect via code that I also attached above

Comment: Why this app later on tries to operate on emulator's localhost (127.0.0.1) even if I forced him (successfully) to connect to computer's localhost (10.0.2.2). Not a single clue.